# Terraform & Ansible controller and private key distribution

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible, terraform

I've got a bunch of servers not provisioned using IaC that are all accessed by SSH from my local machine. I access those servers from 2-3 local machines and I create different private keys per local machine.

I've got a ton of other infra to provision and considered having a cloud provisioning server so that the locals didn't need Terravision and Ansible beyond the initial bootstrap but quickly realised that it would mean having privates keys on a server that most likely would have other users with sudo access. Seems like the best approach is to continue as I am with all private keys local.

I'm going to end up with a load of servers and even more key pairs. It's also probable that I'll have others needing server access.

1. Is the approach I'm taking to provisioning from local machines the best approach or are there alternatives?
2. How do people manage keys at scale - I'm following a principal of a set per access point so that that access can be managed without impacting other access points. My ~/.ssh/config is getting big and feels like I should be generating it from an access source of truth especially as access will be different for different people. What are others doing in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Hashicorp Vault. Your dilemma is one of the reasons Hashicorp Vault was created.

I can assure you to not dive into using Vault casually.  Make sure you have a firm understanding of the deployment and management of Hashicorp Vault.

I was part of a Dev/Ops team that used vault in many environments and regions, development, QA, Test, and Production environments. I personally didn't manage it, so I can't help with any recommendations on how to use Vault.

Take a look at [Vault Agent with AWS](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/agent-aws), to get an idea about Vault.

I recommend using it only in a test environment until you are **absolutely sure**, you know the process of managing the vault.

Oh, another link, [Encrypting content with Ansible Vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html#vault)